# How Thread run starts?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was looking a small example on Threads.For creating Threads we can do in 2 ways either by implementing `Runnable` interface or by extending Thread.I used the 1st way

```
package test;

public class test implements Runnable{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        test t=new test();
        t.run();Thread th=Thread.currentThread();
        th.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

My doubt is when we are calling `th.start();` then `run()` is called.I want to know how.I thought internally there `start()` may be calling `run()` so I looked in the documentation of Thread class

The following is the `start()` declaration in Thread class

```
public synchronized void start() {
    /**
     * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
     * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
     * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
     *
     * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
     */
    if (threadStatus != 0)
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException();

    /* Notify the group that this thread is about to be started
     * so that it can be added to the group's list of threads
     * and the group's unstarted count can be decremented. */
    group.add(this);

    boolean started = false;
    try {
        start0();
        started = true;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (!started) {
                group.threadStartFailed(this);
            }
        } catch (Throwable ignore) {
            /* do nothing. If start0 threw a Throwable then
              it will be passed up the call stack */
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see inside `start()`,`run()` is not called but when we are calling `th.start()` then automatically overriden `run()` is called.Can anybody please throw some light in this

Comment: You might want to review the Java Tutorial on Concurrency specifically the section on threads: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mechanism whereby the `run` method is invoked on a new thread is *extralinguistic*: it cannot be represented in terms of Java code. This is the crucial line in the `start` method:

```
    start0();
```

`start0` is a native method whose invocation will:

- cause a new native thread-of-execution to be created;
- cause the `run` method to be invoked on that thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,so do you mean to say that we can not find out how start() is calling overridden run()?

Comment: No, because it *isn't* calling it. It is indirectly *causing* the run method to be called on a new thread.

Comment: You can inspect the C++ code of the HotpSpot JVM and find the implementation of `start0` there, if you are into that kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks again for answering,Your answer exactly fits to the question.But can you please tell me how to check c++ code of the HotpSpot JVM as you said.I dont know these terms.

Comment: @rocking [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/) is the repository for the latest stable version.

Comment: Here's a starting point: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/ Good luck, you'll need it!

Comment: @Voo I can't for the life of me figure out how to browse to the actual source code from your link.

Comment: I figured it out for @Voo's link, in analogy to mine: you must add /jdk at the end, then it is browseable: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/jdk/file/0dd27693876d/src/share/

Comment: @Marko It's the root of the repository for all the different projects (jdk, hotspot,..). You can browse it, but easier to just clone it locally. Also you won't find the code for `JVM_StartThread` in the jdk directory - that's in HotSpot (jvm.cpp, although it only gets more complicated from there).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Thread th=Thread.currentThread();
    th.start();// its call run method automatically

 if you call direct run method with class object than its treat as a normal method not thread method
```

start() method of Thread class is used to start a newly created thread. It performs following tasks:
A new thread starts(with new callstack).
The thread moves from New state to the Runnable state.
When the thread gets a chance to execute, its target run() method will run.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to call the `run` method. If it does, it will do it in the same running thread.

Just like a program starts in the `main` method of a class, a new thread starts in the `run` method of the class. You have to look into native code to find it.

Comment: It doesn't answer the OP's question

Comment: Correct @KugathasanAbimaran.

Answer (score 0):

Internally start method calls the run method.

Simple experiment may reveal the fact. Call Thread.start() and Thread.run(),, keep a print message statement inside run method. This message will be shown two times because the run method is called two times.

Check this statements in your question code. started flag was false before calling start0, after calling start0() function starrted flag is made true. it means the run method is called withing start0().

```
boolean started = false;

try {
    start0();
    started = true;
}
```

To be precise, the start0 method creates new thred to execute the run method and it returns the current thread.

From oracle official document

" public void start()
Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Throws:
IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.
See Also:
run(), stop() "

Comment: No.  The start() method does _not_ call the run() method.  See Marko Topolnik's answer.  Here's the proof.  Do the experiment that you described above, but don't just print "Hello!" or something;  Print a stack dump (new Exception().printStackTrace(); should do the trick.)  You should see two different stacks:  One from the main thread where you directly called the Thread object's run() method, and one from the new native thread that was created when you called start().  You won't see a call to start() on either stack because run() was never called from within a start() call.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer in documentation of Thread.start() method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()

Comment: The question doesnot answer OPs qustion how run method call frm start

Comment: Yes it does. JVM executes run method of Thread class, so that's the reason why you don't have explicit call from start method.